# sp_refreshView replaces view implementation when sp_rename has occured

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very weird issue with a view which I can reproduce. I'm quite sure that some view metadata is not up to date and causes this issue...

In short:

- I have a view (MyTestView).
- This view is renamed (MyTestViewOld).
- A new view is created with the original name of the renamed view AND a different select query (MyTestView).
- An sp_refreshview is executed on the renamed view (MyTestViewOld).
- Now the implementation of MyTestView is that of MyTestViewOld!

I tried looking into the SP sp_refreshview, but he just executed another SP called sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal. I don't see this view in the system stored procedures of the master database :(

My problem is actually fixed by removing the "MyTestViewOld" **but I would like to know what exactly is going on!** Tnx

Here the script to reproduce the issue! (execute in steps please)

```
--create a test table
create table dbo.MyTestContacts(
    [Title] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Telephone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](255) NULL
    )

--insert data in the temp table
insert dbo.MyTestContacts values ('Mr', 'Holly', 'Buddy', '0123456798', 'buddy@holly.co')
insert dbo.MyTestContacts values ('Mr', 'Valens', 'Ritchie', '987654312', 'ritchie@valens.co')
insert dbo.MyTestContacts values ('Mr', 'Richardson', 'Jiles Perry', '987654312', 'jp@richardson.co')


--create a view
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create view dbo.MyTestView as 
select Title, Name, FirstName from dbo.MyTestContacts
GO


--do a SCRIPT VIEW AS / ALTER TO in sql management studio to verify the view implementation


--rename the view
exec sp_rename 'dbo.MyTestView', 'MyTestViewOld'


--BIS1 (explained below; used in a 2nd test run)


--create a view with the same name as the first view, but different implementation!
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create view dbo.MyTestView as 
select Title, Name, FirstName, Telephone from dbo.MyTestContacts
GO


--do a SCRIPT VIEW AS / ALTER TO in sql management studio to verify the view implementation of MyTestView (telephone is added)


--perform a refreshView action on the MyTestViewOld view
exec sp_refreshview 'dbo.MyTestViewOld'


--do a SCRIPT VIEW AS / ALTER TO in sql management studio to verify the view implementation of MyTestView --> THIS SHOWS THE MyTestViewOld IMPLEMENTATION!!!!


--(BIS1) Note that this sequence gets broken when I do an ALTER VIEW on MyTestViewOld right after the rename!
--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO
--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO
--alter view dbo.MyTestViewOld as 
--select FirstName, Name, Email, Telephone from dbo.MyTestContacts
--GO


--drop everything
drop view dbo.MyTestViewOld
drop view dbo.MyTestView
drop table dbo.MyTestContacts
```

Comment: [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx): "Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored procedures. We recommend you do not use this statement to rename stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, or views; instead, drop the object and re-create it with the new name."

Comment: @deblendewim - interesting, but there is no real reason to call sp_rename on a view, just drop and recreate.

Comment: I completely follow your statement! Even management studio warns me about this action: "Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.". But this still doesn't answer my question which is: what is going on? Maybe my question is too far fetched because it's happening in the internal SQL Server's brain :)

Comment: Well, another quote from the page I linked to is "Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view" which may start to give a clue of what is going on, but I think after that point, it's obscured in internals that we don't have access to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: could you add your first and last comment to an answer? Then this question can be answered ... I need to get on with my developing work and stop worrying about this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) is rather imperfect, and there are lots of warnings against using it on most object types:

> Changing any part of an object name can break scripts and stored procedures. We recommend you do not use this statement to rename stored procedures, triggers, user-defined functions, or views; instead, drop the object and re-create it with the new name.

Whilst there isn't a specific warning about the scenario you've found, there are some clues about the potential path that is leading to the problem arising:

> Renaming a stored procedure, function, view, or trigger will not change the name of the corresponding object name in the definition column of the `sys.sql_modules` catalog view

And, as you've discovered, the internal method that refreshes a view is `sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal` - so I'd suggest it's some form of bug down at the "module" level meta-data internals.

You might want to consider raising the issue on [SQL Server Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer), if for no other reason than for the bug to be documented elsewhere and (maybe) for them to add a further warning to the product documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem as well. I used the following query to identify any views in the database that could cause a problem:

```
select * from (
SELECT o.object_id, o.name, 
Replace(Replace(Replace(SUBSTRING(m.definition,13,(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13),m.definition + CHAR(13)))-13),'[',''),']',''),'dbo.','') as definitionName
FROM sys.objects AS o
left join sys.sql_modules AS m on o.object_id = m.object_id
where o.type='v' )x
where name != definitionName
```