# Using Dots In SQL Server Object Names

Tags: sql-server

**Before you read - this is not about using the dot (this is a legacy issue and someone else wrongly chose to use a dot in the object name). This is a question about the behavior of SQL Server in this particular (bad) situation.**

Our database has two views:

`viewOne` and `viewOne.bkp`

Yes, someone stupidly added a dot in the view name.

An automated script that was generated for these objects from a third party tool had a couple of `sp_refreshview` statements for each of these views.

```
EXEC sp_refreshview N'[ourSchema].[viewOne]'
EXEC sp_refreshview N'[ourSchema].[viewOne.bkp]'
```

When run in the order above, the contents of `viewOne` are overwritten by the contents of `viewOne.bkp`.

Again, given that dots in object names are NOT best practice, and that MS accepts this as a "valid object name", why would the contents of the former be overwritten by the latter if the schema is defined in both statements AND there are two distinct objects present?

Comment: So second `sp_refreshview` doesnt update second view, but instead overwrite first one? or update both?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sp_refreshView replaces view implementation when sp_rename has occured](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17925045/15498)? (Of course, I'm just guessing that an `sp_rename` has occurred in the past, but given the name I'd give it 50:50 odds)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is no `sp_rename` call in the script.

Comment: I have not been able to repro this with new objects. However I can reliably with the views in question. It's video, but see https://www.screencast.com/t/Aro8KXAQ4kl

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and his possible duplicate comment pointed me in a direction.

It looks like although the view name is accepted with a dot, a query to `sys.sql_modules` shows the view contents for both view definitions, old and new, but none for the .bkp version.

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez - no, the point being is that I suspect that `viewOne.bkp` was created, *at some point in the past*, by being renamed from `viewOne`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I cant say when or how it was updated - whether via `sp_rename` or by manually editing the script to create a new view - but I can see after looking in `sys.sql_modules` that both versions of the view are present, and is related to the bug you mention in that question's answer

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your issue. Can you provide code that reproduces the issue?

rextester: http://rextester.com/ZPXB17514

```
/* does sp_refreshview overwrite view definitions? */
create schema ourSchema authorization dbo;
go
create view ourSchema.viewOne as select * from pilots;
go
create view ourSchema.[viewOne.bkp] as select * from flights;
go
select * from ourSchema.ViewOne
select * from ourSchema.[ViewOne.bkp]
go
alter table dbo.pilots  add new int not null default 1;
alter table dbo.flights add new int not null default 1;
go
/* before refresh, doesn't show new columns */
select * from ourSchema.[ViewOne] 
select * from ourSchema.[ViewOne.bkp]
go
EXEC sp_refreshview N'[ourSchema].[viewOne]'
EXEC sp_refreshview N'[ourSchema].[viewOne.bkp]'
go
/* after refresh, shows new columns -- no view overwritten */
select * from ourSchema.[ViewOne]
select * from ourSchema.[ViewOne.bkp]
go
```

Comment: I have been able to repro this reliably. I am working on providing a sample.

Comment: I cant repro this with NEW objects. However I can repro it reliably with these same two existing views. I dont know the context under which these were created (I didnt create or name them), but see https://www.screencast.com/t/Aro8KXAQ4kl